# Updating a field value from checkboxes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, infopath

So I have made a risk assessment form in InfoPath, and am struggling to set a rule/workflow to set a text box (string) field to either yes or no. 
It should be noted that this is a connected to a SharePoint library - not a list because of the extra functionality that this provides.
"Yes" should be the outcome if one or more boxes is "yes" where "no" should be the value if all tick boxes are "no".
I am open to solutions either using rules in InfoPath, or using workflows within SharePoint Designer 2013.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: when using set a field to value in workflows none of my fields within InfoPath appear, I only see - content ID, Name, Workflow name and Title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of the checkboxes on your Infopath form, create a column in the library that it backs onto and set the form to copy the boolean value of that checkbox into the corresponding SharePoint column (can't remember how to do this as I rarely use Infopath but I know it's one of the basic operations).

Once you have all the info as SharePoint columns (which is all the workflow engine understands), you could then do a nested if..else on each value to achieve what you want (bit messy in SPD but it'll work).

Comment: Sorry that isn't working, they were already set as columns in sharepoint.  I think Im misunderstanding your second stage with nested? the fields still arnt showing for some reason

Comment: is nested just the term for else statements?

Comment: the issue is getting the fields to show in "set a field to value" action

Comment: You wont get the Infopath fields to show as an option in a Designer Workflow - their equivalent SharePoint fields should show up, but not the form ones. Designer Workflows can't interact with Infopath forms, only SharePoint lists and libraries. And by nested I mean if statements inside other ones, I forgot for a second Designer can do multi-branch if blocks.

Comment: I have the check boxes showing as columns already, I think I found a solution from what you said, thanks for your help

Comment: i made a column within sharepoint to say yes or no, then a workflow to set it from the check box answers